# Why does TFS 2012 build agent crash when attempt to load invalid XML into XDocument?

Tags: xml

This problem was discovered when parsing MSTest results (.TRX) files: we have some unit tests that output chars to stdout. MSTest stores this output in `<stdout>` node within TRX file. Calling XDocument.Load() on this TRX file should throw, because these chars are invalid for an XML doc. Instead, this triggers TFS build agent to crash.

Using default TFS 2012 workflow 'DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml', in section 'TryToCompiletheProject', add a call to code activity that does this:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    string xmlText = @"<stdout>... &#x1D; ...</stdout>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
}
```

In this area of this workflow, there is a try/catch that should catch the exception, log the exception message, and stop the build. Instead, this crashes the TFS build agent.

Noticed in Windows event log:

```
The build machine will be stopped because an unhandled exception was thrown.
Type: System.ArgumentException
Message: '', hexadecimal value 0x1D, is an invalid character.
Stack Trace:    at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Byte* pDst, Boolean entitize)
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String localName, String value)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking.BuildInformationNode.ToXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking.FileTrackingParticipant.FlushToFile(IList`1 nodesToSave, String file)
```

To avoid this crash, I catch the generated exception and throw a new one with less info. I don't like doing this (loose stack trace to actual source of problem, can't display original exception message), and would prefer to learn another way to log original exception info. And avoid crashing the TFS build agent.

Comment: Try using `ex.ToString()` just to make sure. Better yet, remove the try/catch block and let the framework handle the exception.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I clarified my question, once I was able to find the actual exception thrown, by [attaching debugger to build server process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635150.aspx)

Comment: This looks, to me at least, like the writing of the error by the Build Workflow Process (which is stored as XML) which is trying to write invalid XML. Can you see what the message and other data is that the Build Workflow Process is trying to write?

Comment: @DaveShaw: even if the build agent doesn't crash, the build (worklow) summary and logs don't show the exception message. Other than what I've already shown from Event Logs, where else can I find what you mean?

Comment: @GrumpyCurmudgeon, I thought you managed to attach the debugger to the server build process. Can you not catch the exception and see what's in it. I think John's answer is kind of going the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    try {
        string xmlText = @"<stdout>... &#x1D; ...</stdout>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Can't parse XML Document", ex);
    }
}
```

If this still crashes the build process (perhaps the ex.Message string contains bad XML), then file a bug with Microsoft

Comment: Yes, it still crashes.  With a debugger attached, it appears to me that the invalid chars are displayed in the exception message. [Bug logged with MS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783104/tfs-2012-build-agent-crashes-when-attempt-to-load-invalid-xml-into-xdocument).

Thanks John and @DaveShaw: you were both useful: what is the etiquette on how to mark this question answered? By whom?

Comment: I haven't answered it, so don't accept mine as the answer. If Microsoft has something to say that amounts to an "answer", then you can "Answer" the question yourself and accept it.

Comment: Update from MS: Posted by Microsoft on 4/10/2013 at 6:35 AM:
We were able to reproduce the problem. The exception is being handled by the try/catch. However, the exception message contains the unprintable character. When we attempt to write the exception into the build log, we get a second exception.